# How to get hanging hyphenation?

Tags: xetex, plain-tex, hyphenation, protrusion

I am using XeTeX from TeXLive-2010-Basic in OSX with plain-format.

My try was to follow the TeXbooks setup for commas et such (which I already have working nicely):

```
\defaulthyphenchar=`‐% it is Unicode 2010
\font\rm="TeX Gyre Pagella"
\newdimen\hyphang \setbox0=\hbox{‐} \hyphang=\wd0
\def\hyphen{‐\kern-\hyphang\kern\hyphang}
\catcode`‐=\active \let‐=\hyphen
```

but it didn't work. TeXbook suggests to use "a special font with zero-width `\hyphenchar`", but I don't know how one would go about doing that.

Would you have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you be more explicit? I don't see exactly what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the hypenchar to be a `-` sticking out in the right margin?

Comment: @Bruno Le Floch: I want to get the hyphenation character (whatever that may be) to protrude into the right margin.

Comment: See Konrad's answer below.

Comment: By the way, it’s 2011 now. You should adjust your hyphen char. ;-)

Comment: @Konrad: Haha, I just *knew* someone would make that joke! :-D Btw, that would be "non-breaking hyphen" ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example in the TeXbook is obsolete since all current engines support margin kerning without any tricks.
For plain XeTeX:

```
\XeTeXprotrudechars=2
\font\rm="TeX Gyre Pagella"\relax
\rm
\rpcode\font\XeTeXcharglyph\hyphenchar\font=250
\hsize=20mm
a a a a a a a a a abbabbabb aabbabbabb abbabb
\bye
```

`\XeTeXprotrudechars=2` activates protrusion, the `\rpcode` line sets the protrusion code of the glyph the hyphen character maps to.

Comment: Thanks! What does the `\font=250` mean?

Comment: @morbusg. `\hyphenchar\font=250` means that the hyphenation character for the current font is in position 250 in that font.

Comment: Not quite; that line of code says: set the right protrusion (`\rpcode`) of the current font (`\font`) for the character used for hyphenation (`\XeTeXcharglyph\hyphenchar\font`) to 0.250em (`=250`). (I know I'm late to the party but just wanted to ensure this didn't confuse anyone down the track…)

Comment: In the question, @morbusg creates a box to ensure that the hang depth is equal to the width of the character. This answer hard codes the solution at 0.250em. If the font were to change, this value might not be correct. How would you recover the non-hard-coded size of the question?

Answer (score 7):

You can try installing the [current beta of the `microtype` package](http://xetex.tk/mediawiki/index.php/Microtype_package_%28preliminary_version%29). Its support of XeTeX is incomplete but protrusion (and hence hanging hyphenation) already works and despite its beta status I haven’t (so far) experienced any difficulties with it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but reading the documentations "getting started"-part, isn't `microtype` a LaTeX package?

Comment: @morbusg: yes it is. I missed the `plain-tex` tag on your question and I thought you were just using a TeX solution because LaTeX has no obvious advantage here.

Comment: @morbusg. It is, but within it you will doubtless find the appropriate code (although it does seem Philipp has already done that job!)