# XeLaTeX and Microtype

Tags: xetex, microtype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Margin kerning in Xe(La)TeX for TeXlive 2010: how to enable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2986/margin-kerning-in-xelatex-for-texlive-2010-how-to-enable)

Is it possible to get `microtype` to work with XeLaTeX? Is there any other alternatives to that kind of tweaking? I really think that documents which have gone through `microtype`tweaking have superior aesthetics.

Update: After going [here](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/action=view/id=423), which seems to have a beta version of `microtype` that works with XeTeX, and unzipping it to `TEXMFLOCAL`:

```
unzip -d `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL` Microtype.zip
```

I still get the following error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty

Package microtype Warning: You don't seem to be using pdftex.
(microtype)                `microtype' only works with pdftex.
(microtype)                Try running `pdflatex' instead of `xelatex'.
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2986/margin-kerning-in-xelatex-for-texlive-2010-how-to-enable Relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/drawbacks-of-xetex-luatex/3099#3099 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8122/how-to-get-hanging-hyphenation/8127#8127 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7629/moving-from-pdflatex-to-xetex-what-do-i-need-to-know/7631#7631

Comment: Use the `tds` package when unpacking to a texmf tree.

Comment: @Andrey microtype does more than margin kerning, doesn't it? Wouldn't that mean that this wasn't a duplicate?

Comment: @Seamus: That question ultimately asks the same thing, how to use `microtype` with XeLaTeX. Either way round, one of the two is a duplicate of another.

Comment: @Andrey I think we should _merge_ the questions rather than close this one, since this one has the more general title.